# Count multiple like patterns and aggregate by date

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have a table inside a Postgresql database with two columns, text (string) and date. I want to search for how many times a string pattern has occurred in any text in a given day. I have

```
SELECT date(date), count(date) FROM table WHERE LOWER(text)
LIKE %pattern% AND date BETWEEN start AND end GROUP BY date(date) ORDER BY 1;
```

And this gives me a column of dates with counts,

```
             0    1
0   2020-09-09  714
1   2020-09-10  662
2   2020-09-11  530
3   2020-09-12  591
4   2020-09-13  669
..         ...  ...
85  2020-12-03  908
86  2020-12-04  839
87  2020-12-05  779
88  2020-12-06  758
89  2020-12-07  805
```

If I have multiple keywords, and I want a separate column counting the number of times each keyword has appeared in a day, how do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT date::date, 
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE LOWER(text) LIKE '%pattern1%') as cnt1,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE LOWER(text) LIKE '%pattern2%') as cnt2
FROM table 
WHERE date BETWEEN ... AND ...
GROUP BY date::date
ORDER BY 1;
```

Note that you - probably - could use `text ILIKE ...` instead of `LOWER(text) LIKE ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` for conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT date(date), count(date),
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE text LIKE '%keyword1%') as cnt_1,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE text LIKE '%keyword2%') as cnt_2
FROM table 
WHERE date BETWEEN start AND end
GROUP BY date(date)
ORDER BY 1;
```

Whether you need to take `case` into account depends on the collation of your columns.  If you have case sensitive collations (the default), then use `ilike`:

```
SELECT date(date), count(date),
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE text ILIKE '%keyword1%') as cnt_1,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE text ILIKE '%keyword2%') as cnt_2
FROM table 
WHERE date BETWEEN start AND end
GROUP BY date(date)
ORDER BY 1;
```

If these are really keywords, you might want to use regular expressions to find only words surrounded by word boundaries.  That is just a heads-up because your question does not provide sample data and desired results.